# Correlation matrix between vectors of different sizes

Tags: r, cross-correlation, pearson-correlation

I'm trying to implement a correlation matrix for unbalanced data, it is possible? My code below shows I've been trying to do. Someone could help me with this question?

## My code

## Variables

```
var1<-rnorm(200,5,0.25)##  200 values
var2<-1:500 ## 500 values
var3<-rnorm(100,5,0.25)## 100 values
var4<-500:1## 500 values
```

## Correlation matrix function

```
pn <- function(X){crossprod(!is.na(X))}

cor.prob <- function(X){
     pair.SampSize <- pn(X)
     above1 <- row(pair.SampSize) < col(pair.SampSize)
     pair.df <- pair.SampSize[above1] - 2

     R <- cor(X, use="pair")
     above2 <- row(R) < col(R)
     r2 <- R[above2]^2
     Fstat <- (r2 * pair.df)/(1 - r2)
     R[above2] <- 1 - pf(Fstat, 1, pair.df)
     R
     }


correla <- round(cor.prob(var1,var2,var3,var4),4)
```

## Doesn't work

Thanks

Comment: You'll probably have to explain what "doesn't work" mean to you.

Comment: You need to explain how calculating the correlation between vectors of different sizes is supposed to work mathematically.

Comment: I thinking in create a sample function with the 100 values dimension and repeat 1000 times.

Comment: Do you mean like a "full information" estimator for the covariance matrix? If so, then yes, it's possible, and likelihood estimators of that type are commonplace in many statistical software packages (e.g., `lavaan` for full information ML in R). In general, a relatively simple framework for that kind of computation is the EM algorithm by Dempster, Laird & Rubin (1977; see http://www.jstor.org/stable/2984875).